# ng-if appearing properly when length > 0, but not appearing when length === 0

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a pretty simple ng-if that's based on the length of an array. If the length is greater than zero, it displays the length. If it's zero, it says it's empty. It's displaying when the length is greater than zero, but not when it is zero. Anyone see what I'm missing here?

Here's my HTML (the ng-if's in question are on lines 5 and 9, but I thought I'd put the surrounding HTML in there in case there's something around there I'm missing):

```
<div class="employee-box" ng-repeat="employee in sigFigCtrl.companies[$index].employees">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit pull-right" ng-click="sigFigCtrl.toggleEmployeeEdit($index)"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" ng-click="sigFigCtrl.deletePerson(employee._id, $index, sigFigCtrl.companies[$parent.$index].employees)"></span>
        <div ng-show="!sigFigCtrl.companies[$index].editEmployee">
            <div ng-if="sigFigCtrl.companies[$index].employees.length > 0">
                <p><b>Name:</b> {{employee.name}}</p>
                <p><b>Email:</b> {{employee.email}}</p>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="sigFigCtrl.companies[$index].employees.length === 0">
                empty array!
            </div>
        </div>
    <div ng-show="sigFigCtrl.companies[$index].editEmployee">
        <form name="editPersonForm" ng-submit="sigFigCtrl.editPerson(employee._id, $index)">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="text" ng-model="sigFigCtrl.editPersonName" id="name" placeholder="Name of Employee" class="form-control" required></input>
            </div>
        </div>            <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="text" ng-model="sigFigCtrl.editPersonEmail" id="name" placeholder="Email of Employee" class="form-control" required></input>
        </div>
            <button>SUBMIT</button>
        </form>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is quite simple. You’re doing a repeat on `sigFigCtrl.companies[$index].employees`. Which means when there’s no elements it will never run. Think in it as loop like `for each` or `for`. If there are no elements the iteration will never run. That’s why you never actually reach the inside `ngIf` where you’re testing if it has elements or not. It’s stopped at the root

Comment: Ah! Yep, that was it. Thank you very much.

Comment: No worries. Always glad to help. Please don’t forget to check the question as answered in order to help others with similar issue.

Comment: Are you still free to help? I'm running into something else new that's confusing me.